# Tensorflow, printing loss function causes error without feed_dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just reading Tensorflow documentation. In following code, I just changed last line. I pushed last line in iteration, to see what exactly is going on...

```
import tensorflow as tf

# linear_model = W*x+B

W = tf.Variable(.3, dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.Variable(-3., dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32) #data_X
linear_model = W*x+B

y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32) #data_Y

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model-y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

X_train = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0] #data_X
y_train = [0.0,-1.0,-2.0,-3.0] #data_y

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(train,{x:X_train, y:y_train})
        print(sess.run([W,B,loss], {x:X_train, y:y_train}))
```

Please check the very last line: `print(sess.run([W,B,loss], {x:X_train, y:y_train}))`

Why do I need to include

```
{x:X_train, y:y_train}
```

in order to print statement out? If you exclude this from the last line, you will get error. It makes no sense, because loss is already calculated in line before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line before is probably calculating loss internally in your `train` op, but it is not outputting anything. Your print statement, therefore, needs to first calculate those values, for which you need to pass the `feed_dict`. You could get around this syntax by changing the last two lines to:

```
_, W_val, B_val, loss_val = sess.run([train, W, B, loss], {x: X_train, y:y_train})  # run ops all at once, storing desired results
print(W_val, B_val, loss_val)  # do whatever you want with stored results
```

The first line above actually executes the `W`, `B`, and `loss` ops explicitly and saves their values to `W_val`, `B_val`, and `loss_val`. You can do whatever you want with those saved values then.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you print out `loss`, you'll see that it's a Tensor, not a variable. This is because TensorFlow defines a computation graph, then executes it when you call `sess.run`, it doesn't perform sequential execution like python.

You can think of `loss` as a function of x and y to see what `sess.run` is doing.

```
execute loss()   # not enough information to calculate loss
execute loss(x, y) # this will run loss
```